# The gem simple_form displays numbers instead of associated stings, when using the enums introduced in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Rails 4.1 introduced [enum](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/4/8/Rails-4-1/), which don't play well with the latest version of simple_form. When used with associations, simple_form displays numbers instead of the associated stings. Any solutions or work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your Gemfile

```
# Help ActiveRecord::Enum feature to work fine with I18n and simple_form.
gem 'enum_help'
```

Learn more [here](https://github.com/zmbacker/enum_help)